# python source code with using realgud:gdb and pdb

Tags: python, gdb, realgud

Following invokes pdb in shell. I have to type list to look at the python source. Instead is there a way to open the python source file, just like how the c++ source file is opened when a gdb breakpoint is hit? It maybe because pdb is invoked instead realgud:pdb?

```
/auto/sw/gdb -ex 'add-auto-load-safe-path /users/ap/project1' --args env 
/auto/sw/python/bin/pytest -s -vvvs --pdb --trace test/python/test1.py

/auto/sw/python/bin/pytest is a python binary which triggers test/python/test1.py
```

Comment: What does "to open the python source file, just like how the c++ source file is opened when a gdb breakpoint is hit" mean?  Python is written in C, not C++. For me, pytest is an executable bash shell script in ASCII, not a binary.  At least for me, there is too much clairvoyance around what it is that you are trying to do, and what you'd like to see. Maybe giving a full sequence of what you run and what you see and what you expect to see would clarify?